# "Either" and "too" in pairs of sentences

Tags: grammar

I wrote these sentences:

> ①  I am unable to speak. I am unable to hear **either**.
>
> ② I felt humiliated at the party last night. I was unable to sleep well, **too**.

Here is my analysis:  In ①, the first sentence is negative and the second one is negative as well. For this reason, ***either*** is used.

But in ② the first sentence is positive, and though *unable* is negative, since the first sentence is positive, ***too*** is used.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Because in English, disjunctive relationships are generally inclusive, if you can say about something _this or that_, then you can use _either_ or _too_: _I can't speak or hear/I can't speak. I can't hear, either/too._ For the same reason, you can use either _either_ or _too_ when it's a conjunctive relationship: _I felt humiliated at the party last night, and I was unable to sleep well/I felt humiliated at the party last night. I was unable to sleep well, either/too._ **tl;dr your analysis is incomplete and overly simplifies the logico-semantics of the conjunctions used.**

Comment: Nico says both are grammatical.

Comment: yes - they are grammatical, but your question was whether your analysis was correct, and not about the grammaticality of the sentences (which I didn't question).

Comment: The Phrase: "The old method of learning English didn't work, other methods won't work, too." Is that phrase correct or should I use *either* instead of *too*?

Comment: @Elizeu - I think _either_ sounds better, but I don't know if I'd say that the version with _too_ would be "incorrect."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are grammatical. In ① and ②, both [either](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/either) and [too](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/too) are working as adverbs.

Adverbs (and more generally adverbial phrases) can complement verbs, adjectives or, as in ① and ②, clauses.

> I am unable to hear **either**.

*"Either"* in the above sentence complements the whole clause *"I am unable to hear"*. It is used to indicate that the clause is adding some information to the preceeding sentence. As noted by the OP, *"either"* is used for this purpose only when both sentences express negation. In ①, *"unable"* provides this negative meaning in both sentences.

Other examples of this usage of *either* (taken from the dictionary linked above):

> You don’t like him, do you? I don’t, **either**.
>   It won’t do any harm, but won’t really help, **either**.
>   I was too tired to go. And I couldn’t have paid my way, **either**.

If any of the sentences, as in example ②, does not express negation, then the adverb *"either"* is infelicitous, and *"too"* should be used instead:

---

Note that both *"either"* and "*too*" link one clause with the preceding sentence, and hence, there must be a reason to link them.

In the case of ①, both sentences follow the same pattern: *"I am unable to"*.

In the case of ②, more context is needed to make this reason patent, e.g.:

> **Yesterday was a terrible day:** I felt humiliated at the party last night. I was unable to sleep well, too.

Comment: @username901345 By "infelicitous" I mean that one has to consider the meaning of the sentences to determine that the use of "either" isn't appropriate in ②.

Comment: @username901345 I've updated the answer to try to clarify that example ② is grammatical.