# Should I use 'either' or 'too' after 'have no idea'?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Which of the two following sentences is correct?

> I have no idea what is going on too.

> I have no idea what is going on either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Either" and "too" in pairs of sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31144/either-and-too-in-pairs-of-sentences)

Answer (score 0):

> ❌ I have no idea what is going on too.

This one feels wrong to me, but I can't place my finger on why. I would instead say "I too, have no idea what is going on". It might have to do with the negative ("no idea"). If it was a "positive" sentence like

> ✅ I have an idea of what's going on too.

that would feel fine to me.

> ✅ I have no idea what is going on either.

This one feels fine to me.

Just to include comparison with the previous "positive" example I added, the following feels wrong to me:

> ❌ I have an idea of what is going on either.

Answer (score -2):

I think 'too' should be after 'I' instead of after 'on', if ever 'too' is correct to use. I believe the 'either' is correctly placed if 'either' is correct to use. I have a feeling either is for exactly 2 people similar to 'both' and 'neither'. not so sure. But both sound ok. See [Drop the Mic | Shania Twain vs Meghan Trainor](https://youtu.be/xPsK1PGhW8I?t=236) Shania says at 3:56  'I didn't wanna do this either.'

[image]